# Cannot start session using selenium/standalone-chrome:4.12.1-20230912 docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run my tests in a docker container as suggested in [seleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/trunk).

I started my container as:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" --name=chrome-node selenium/standalone-chrome:4.12.1-20230912
```

I'm pointing my webdriver as follows:

```py
def driver(request): 
    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    print(f"Creating {browser} driver")

    if browser == "docker-chrome":
        time.sleep(5)
        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox");
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        chrome_prefs = {}
        chrome_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
        chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
        my_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=docker_url,
                                      options=chrome_options)
    
    elif browser == "docker-firefox":
        firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
        my_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=docker_url,
                          options=firefox_options)

    else:
        raise TypeError(f"Got {browser}, chrome or firefox expected")
    #my_driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    yield my_driver
    print(f"Closing {browser} driver")
    my_driver.quit()

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome", help="browser to execute tests (chrome or firefox)")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```bash
WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: '541128bb367e', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Any advice?

tried to use desired_capabilities, add different chrome_options arguments. Same error